# How do I get ngx-mask npm package for masking phone numbers in Angular to work?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the ngx-mask npm package to work. The instructions are as follow:

Package found here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

```
import {NgxMaskModule} from 'ngx-mask'

export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>);

@NgModule({
  (...)
  imports: [
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(options)
  ]
  (...)
})
```

But I am getting an error on the second line:

```
export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>);
```

The error says "const options" declaration must be initialized. What do I initialized it to?

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize to null since it is a interface

```
import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';
export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>) = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this problem. install npm i ngx-mask@14.2.4 this version ;)

Comment: This was helpful to me. My angular version is 14.x. I installed the most recent version of ngx-mask (15), but it didn't work. So I installed version 14.2.4 instead. For some reason, the command you listed did work for me, so I used this instead: npm i ngx-mask@14.2.4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I decided to update the import form in app.module.ts as per the new guidance:

```
import { NgxMaskDirective, NgxMaskPipe, provideNgxMask } from 'ngx-mask';


 imports: [
    [...]
    NgxMaskDirective,
    NgxMaskPipe
  ],
  
  providers: [
    provideNgxMask()
  ],
```

Since ng14 and not in ng15 we have changes in API that we described in https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask

Please check this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-mc8tvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts try like this:

```js
import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';

export let options: Partial | (() => Partial);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  NgxMaskModule.forRoot(options)],
 }
})
```

[Source](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/issues/128)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
import { NgxMaskModule} from 'ngx-mask';
```

to

```
import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';
```